# What is the purpose of an Array.prototype.map() invocation with an arrow function with two inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial on React.js, and am at the section https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#showing-the-moves where I see the following code snippet within a `React.Component`'s `render` method:

```
const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Go to move #' + move :
    'Go to game start';
  return (
    <li>
      <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Here, `history` is an array of objects having a `square` property:

```
history = [
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
    ]
  },
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, 'X', null,
      null, null, null,
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

What I don't understand is why the arrow function in `history.map` has two inputs, `step` and `move`. In the documentation for `map`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map, I only see examples of arrow functions with one input (namely, the array element in question). I also don't see the `step` input used anywhere in the arrow method's body so I'm not sure what it's purpose is. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Look under the "parameters" section in that documentation. The callback can accept 3 arguments:  currentValue, index, and array. `step` is the currentValue, `move` is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example move is index of each step. Using this index you can find specified step in history.

Answer (score 1):

For every item in the array, they're creating what I suppose is some kind of React component.

How they're using the second parameter (the array index) is as the boolean evaluated condition of the conditional operator `? :`.

So because the only "falsey" number is `0` (other than `NaN`), when the index is `0` (the first iteration), the `desc` will be `"Go to game start"`, otherwise it's the other message with the position.

Here's a simplified non-React demonstration:

```js
const history = ["these", "values", "are", "ignored"];

const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Go to move #' + move :
    'Go to game start';
  return desc;
});

console.log(moves);
```

So you can see that when the index was `0`, instead of giving a message to go to that "step" represented by the index number, it gives the clearer message to go to the start.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in `map` is index. This may helps you to navigate in `history`.

```js
let history = [
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
    ]
  },
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, 'X', null,
      null, null, null,
    ]
  }
]

history.map((step, move) => console.log("step: ", step, "\nindex (move): ", move))
```